# Duplicates in a sequence using ONLY for loops in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, function

Given a sequence, I was wondering how to find duplicates using **ONLY** for loops (no imported modules, sorting functions, and etc.) in Python. Here's my following code that involves nested for loops so far:

```
def has_duplicates(list):
    x = 0
    ans = False
    for i in range(len(list)):
        index = i
        for object in list:
            x = object
        if list[i] == x:
            ans = True
            break
    return ans
```

I really do not know what to code for the inner loop... Are nested loops even necessary to find the duplicates of a sequence?

Examples of following outputs:

```
list = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
print(ans)
False
list = "Hello"
print(ans)
True
```

Comment: You need to call the function at least, and use the return value.

Comment: are you allowed to use `set` ?

Comment: "I can only use for loops" is an ambiguous statement. What about function defintions, user-defined function calls, built-in function calls, assignment statements, int literals, boolean literals, list literals, binary operators, if blocks, return statements, break statements, and print statements? Because you're using all of those too, right now. Please ask your teacher to be more specific about what you may or may not use.

Comment: @Kevin I love how obvious it is that this is a homework assignment.

Comment: Is `enumerate` allowed?

Comment: Oh no, i should ask it too before writing the answer

Comment: @Kevin, all of those are allowed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, **we iterate over the current list checking for duplicates from the 2nd element onwards and seeing if that particular element exists anywhere at the beginning of the list.**

To get the sub-list starting from index `0` uptill the current index we use the `slice[:]` operation in list and to check if the current element exists in that sub-list, we use the `in` operator.

You can do the following:

```
In [1]: def has_duplicates(my_list):
   ...:     for index in range(len(my_list)): 
   ...:         if index!=0: # check only from 2nd element onwards
   ...:             item = my_list[index] # get the current item
   ...:             if item in my_list[:index]: # check if current item is in the beginning of the list uptill the current element
   ...:                 return True # duplicate exist
   ...:     return False # duplicate does not exist
   ...:

In [2]: has_duplicates([1,2,3,4])
Out[2]: False

In [3]: has_duplicates([1,2,3,4,4])
Out[3]: True

In [4]: has_duplicates([1,1,2,3,4,4])
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a much more efficient lookahead comparison for each element; this eliminates redundant comparisons throughout the list by only comparing each element to the ones which follow it. I'm not a Python programmer, so I'm only guessing this will work; it probably is the least idiomatic solution to this problem, as well (meaning Python probably has prettier ways of handling this, but it ought to work just fine).

```
def has_duplicates(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
            if list[i] == list[j]:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Since you commented on time complexity elsewhere, I'd just like to point out that this is `O(n^2)` as well, since it's only quicker than the naive solution by a constant factor of ~2. The _efficient_ solution uses hashing.

Comment: @tzaman True, this isn't much more efficient; it's still the same complexity, but it does cut out a lot of excess, *almost* to the point of `n log n`. I'd love to see the efficient solution; could you write it up as an answer?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. Your way cuts out about half of the work; `O(n^2 / 2)` is still _incredibly far_ from being `n lg n`. The whole point of dropping constant factors in big-O notation is because they are more or less irrelevant as `n` grows. Your solution is still very firmly in the `O(n^2)` bucket. The more efficient would use `set` so it's not allowed under OP's criteria, but @Peter Wood is close.

Comment: Your answer is about as efficient as it can get under the rules specified though, so +1.

Comment: Oh, derp. Yeah, I don't know why I thought that was close to `n lg n`. I should probably get more coffee.

Comment: If you want to make it a little more pythonic, you can skip the `range(len(..))` stuff and just iterate over values: `for i in lst: .. for j in lst[i+1:]: .. if i == j` - also, don't name the variable `list` since that shadows the builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Take slices of the un-iterated values:

```
def has_duplicates(values):
    for index, value in enumerate(values, start=1):
        for other_value in values[index:]:
            if value == other_value:
                return True
    return False
```

If you can use sets:

```
def has_duplicates(values):
    return len(values) > len(set(values))
```

Comment: The OP specifies that they're not allowed to use `set` in their comments.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Well, that burst my bubble.

Answer (score 0):

As, there are some suggestions from performance point of view, my solution is from readability point of view. Better use `enumerate` to grab `index`.

```
def has_duplicates(list):

    for index,value  in enumerate(list):
        for index2,value2  in enumerate(list):
            if value==value2 and index!=index2:
                return True


    return False

print has_duplicates("Hello")
print has_duplicates([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: @ShotgunNinja, off course, i wrote it above. I have written it to make it as simple as i can.

Comment: But yeah, this is a pretty clever and idiomatic way to solve this clearly.